# Set elasticsearch initial password via docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Can i know, how to set initial password for elasticsearch database using docker-compose

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto -u "http://192.168.2.120:9200
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/docker.html#_image_types):

> The initial password can be set at start up time via the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable:
>
> `docker run -e ELASTIC_PASSWORD=MagicWord docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-platinum:6.1.4`

Also, for newest image (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0), the `ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE` environment added mentioned in [Configuring Elasticsearch with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods):

> For example, to set the Elasticsearch bootstrap password from a file, you can bind mount the file and set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE environment variable to the mount location. If you mount the password file to /run/secrets/bootstrapPassword.txt, specify:
>
> `-e ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/bootstrapPassword.txt`

So add these environment in `docker-compose.yaml` I guess could work for you.